# converting NSData to UIImage - working with NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsurlconnection, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I've been working with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager calling my service that return an image and my code looked like this:

```
NSString *baseURLString = @"http://get_image/";

@try {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseURLString
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSString *imageStr = responseObject[0];
              if([imageStr isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]==NO)
              {
              NSData *imageData = [NSData   dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageStr];
              UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
              self.myImage = (image==nil)? [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto"]: image;
              }
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             self.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto"];
         }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception %@", exception);
}
```

since AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is async and I need a sync call how can I complete this code to produce my image:

```
NSString *baseURLString = @"http://get_image/";
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p_baseURLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];

// Make synchronous request
NSData *imageRequest = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

???

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.displayedApartment.exteriorImage = (image==nil)? [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPhoto"]: image;
```

This is what I've tried in place of ??? all resulted in image=nil

- using the imageRequest data as is
- converting the imageRequest to base64 with `[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:imageRequest options:0];`
- converting it to string and back to NSData

  `NSData NSString *imageStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[imageRequest bytes]];
  NSData *imageData = [NSData   dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageStr];`

Comment: Have you tried using the AFNetworking UIImage category methods?  They are designed so that you pass only the URL of the image and then AFNetworking handles the download and updating of the UIImageView with the image.

Comment: I might be missing something but in your code yo have p_baseURLString as the variable that holds the url of the image but I can't see this variable declared. Have you typo'd baseURLString. Have you also checked any error returned (you capture it but don't check for an error). I would not expect you to need to do anything to the returned data unless the server is doing something funky.

Comment: why do u use @try/@catch here?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, I think your variable names might be causing some trouble. Try replacing the following line:

```
NSData *imageRequest = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

with

```
NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

and then see what `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` gives you. Unless there has been an error in the request, I can't see a reason why `image` wouldn't be properly instantiated unless it didn't represent an image object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just display the image using the AFNetworking function         setImageWithURL, it takes the URL of an image and sets the UIImageView to that image. Its a much simpler way of doing things if you only need to display it.

It looks something like this:

```
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p_baseURLString]];
```

In the header file you'll have something like this:

```
      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Its much faster as well.